# Javascript object data binding with Vue

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I have a JavaScript object that I am attempting to bind to a Vue view.

I am running a function to update the JavaScript object using AJAX and I was expecting Vue to bind to the JS object and update the view when the object is updated though that isn't happening.

Research suggests making the AJAX call within the Vue declaration but due other constraits I would rather not do that.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate what the issue is since it's reproducable without the AJAX portion as well as pasted the code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/g6u2tph7/5/

Thanks in advance for your time and wisdom.

Thanks,

vmitchell85

**JavaScript**

```
window.changeTheData = function (){
    externalJSSystems =  [{description: 'Baz'}, {description: 'Car'}];
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = 'function has ran...';
    // This doesn't update the Vue data

}

var externalJSSystems = [{description: 'Foo'}, {description: 'Bar'}];

Vue.component('systable', {
    template: '#sysTable-template',
    data() {
        return {
            systems: externalJSSystems
        };
    }
});
new Vue({
   el: 'body'
});
```

**HTML**

```
<systable :systems="systems"></systable>

<button type="button" onclick="changeTheData()">Change</button>
<br><br>
<div id="log"></div>
<template id="sysTable-template">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="sys in systems">
                <td>{{ sys.description }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out :

```
externalJSSystems.push({description: 'Baz'}, {description: 'Car'});
```

It will append the new objects to *externalJSSystems* and the view will be updated. Why doesn't your example work ? Because you are assigning a new `Array` reference to *externalJSSystems* but Vue is still watching the old one.

To achieve what you want, don't assign a new `Array` instance but clear it. For example :

```
window.changeTheData = function (){
    externalJSSystems.length = 0
    externalJSSystems.push({description: 'Baz'}, {description: 'Car'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is just a quick example I put together and I'm not sure how this would work in my actual code... let me test this out and see if it would work...

Comment: This does in fact work however I must loop through every entry to push each one individually instead of just update the object with the whole new dataset - I also tried to set the whole object and then push one more entry and it still doesn't update - If I can't find a better solution then I'll mark this one as the answer (or is that bad practice?)

Comment: zxzak or @ShadowScripter - Is there a suggestion for when the JS variable is an object and not an array?

Answer (score 2):

When that instance of the `systable` Component is instantiated, Vue adds an "Observer" class to the initial `externalJSSystems` Array — extending the Array's prototype, adding getter/setters for each of the properties, and maintaining the two-way binding between the Component's `data` and the original Array. The `changeTheData()` method is overwriting that Vue-modified `externalJSSystems` Array with a completely new Array (that lacks the Observer), thus breaking the two-way binding.

In this way, `externalJSSystems.push( … )` works because the default Array methods ('push', 'pop', 'shift', 'unshift', 'splice', 'sort', and 'reverse') have been mutated such that they are handled by the Observer.

I think the key to the behavior you're looking for lies in the Vue Component "props" — http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props. In fact, it looks like your component markup — `<systable :systems="systems"></systable>` — is already set up to pass dynamic data to the Component instance. Right now, that `:systems="systems"` isn't doing anything. By defining `systems` in the Parent Vue scope, and defining `systems` as a `prop(s)` within the Component registration, you can pass dynamic data to Components within that Parent's scope.

**Component**

```
Vue.component('systable', {
  template: '#sysTable-template',
  props: {
    systems: Array
  }
});
```

**Vue Instance**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    systems: externalJSSystems
  }
});
```

You can see it in action in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/ycr12dgw/

I cached the Vue instance — `var vm = new Vue({ … })` — so the `changeTheData` method had access to its `systems` data. *This gives your external `changeTheData()` method a reference to the Vue instance where you defined `system` — thus giving it access to modify (without replacing, or iteratively adding/removing items from…) the Array of data.*

Comment: Thanks for the info about the observer, it makes more sense now but I'm not sure I'll be able to do what i need to do. I added the button click function to mock my AJAX call to get data that I didn't want to put into Vue. Now I'm thinking it may just be better to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making systems a data property, you can make it a computed property.  Like the other answer said, the reference is to the old object.  But if you make `systems` a computed property, it will automatically watch any variable used in the calculation (like `externalJSSystems`) and re-calculate the computed property.

```
Vue.component('systable', {
template: '#sysTable-template',
computed: {
    systems() {
        return externalJSSystems;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work... can you create a fiddle?